# What is a "remedy" for a "pitfall"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am writing an academic thesis related to a specific topic (the actual topic is irrelevant, so let's just call it XXX). The thesis basically consists of:

1. pointing out a couple of problems in existing literature related to XXX,
2. methodology that according to my research can be used to lessen these problems, and
3. some more or less random extensions to the topics covered.

My working title for the thesis is "XXX: Pitfalls, Remedies, and Extensions". I like it in the sense that it reflects the three aspects described above – without referring to "problems" too directly.

However, what I do not like is my feeling that there are no "remedies" for "pitfalls", are there? I would assume that remedies exist for illnesses and such, whereas a pitfall you can for instance avoid, or circumvent – but how to express this in such a title?

Alternatively, replacements for the word "pitfalls" can be suggested, even though in my opinion it fits in rather nicely regarding the specific issues that the thesis happens to address. Finally, reworking the whole title can be suggested as well, of course – I've already considered just "XXX", but I feel that it is not a very good match regarding the actual contents of the thesis.

**Edit**: "XXX" is "Overfitting in Feature Selection".

Comment: I still think it would help if you defined XXX, since you suggest that rephrasing the entire title is an option. "Extensions to", for example, might sound a bit odd to me in this context (could be just me), unless it fits XXX.

Comment: Edited. Now that you mention it, I do agree that it sounds a bit odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Workarounds* would be one possibility, although it might be too technical, and it might imply that the solution is only temporary while waiting for a better one. Alternatively *Solutions* might be the word you are searching for.

Comment: "Solutions" seems to be the best suggestion so far. Indeed, I am thinking of dropping "Extensions", because "Solutions" might include them, too. (And as pointed out by Cerberus's comment, the word "Extensions" does not really fit in.) Therefore, my current working title is "XXX: Pitfalls and Solutions" - but I am not accepting this answer just yet, because I would love to receive at least one more suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try "precautions," as it gives you both the desired sense and some snazzy alliteration.